# Different results with Mathematica for Integrate and NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

Trying to find a symbolic solution to an integral with `Integrate`:

```
Integrate[SinIntegral[x^11]/x^(7), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

The solution found is:

```
-(11/72) (-1)^(5/22) (-1 + (-1)^(6/11)) Gamma[5/11]
```

The numerical value is computed by typing:

```
-(11/72) (-1)^(5/22) (-1 + (-1)^(6/11)) Gamma[5/11] // N
```

The numerical result is:

```
0.449925 -8.32667*10^-17 I
```

Another way of coding:

```
Limit[Integrate[SinIntegral[x^11]/x^(7), {x, 0, a}], a -> Infinity]
```

The result here is:

```
(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[5/22])/(12 2^(6/11) Gamma[14/11])
```

The numerical result here is:

```
0.449925
```

I could assume that the complex result is nearly equal to zero, and the two results found are equal.

But when I use `NIntegrate` and type

```
NIntegrate[SinIntegral[x^11]/x^(7), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

The value yielded is

```
0.197976
```

The numerical value with `NIntegrate` is given without error notifications and is the same for increasing `WorkingPrecision`.

Why the different numerical results between `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`?

Answer (score 7):

It's a highly oscillating integrand, so `NIntegrate` is likely to have trouble.  (I guess that's why the error estimate is fooled -- the integrand doesn't change sign, tho.)  This gets about 6 digits right:

```
NIntegrate[SinIntegral[x^11]/x^(7), {x, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
(*  0.44992539271339646829381032087665  *)
```

This also gets close, much faster:

```
NIntegrate[SinIntegral[x^11]/x^7, {x, 0, ∞}, MinRecursion -> 4]
(*  0.449925  *)
```

Finally, turning off the Levin Rule, which seems to be used here, gives an OK result:

```
NIntegrate[SinIntegral[x^11]/x^(7), {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
(*  0.449922  *)
```

This can be made more precise by raising `MinRecursion` or adding division points to the iterator, e.g., `{x, 0, 2, Infinity}`, to capture the major contribution to the integral.